# Как можно через jquery сделать анимацию с помощью rotate?

Tags: jquery, css3

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на эту стрелочку она поворачивалась налево, при втором нажатии обратно вниз. Не могу понять, как написать код. Сворачивание нижнего блока при нажатии на стрелку уже сделал.

КОД [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function blockDescription(){
$(".button-edit").click(function(){
    var description =$('.block-description');
    if(description.is(':visible')){
        description.hide();
    }
    else {
        description.show();
    }


  });

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, как Вы хотели, через transform rotate

```js
blockDescription();

function blockDescription(){
  $('.block-description').hide()
  $(".button-edit").click(function(){
    var description = $('.block-description');
    let visible = description.is(':visible');
    visible ? description.hide() : description.show();
    let rot = 'rotate(' + (visible ? 0 : 90) + 'deg)';
    $(".button-edit").css({
        '-webkit-transform': rot,
        '-moz-transform': rot,
        '-ms-transform': rot,
        '-o-transform': rot,
        'transform': rot
      })
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button-edit" >></button>
<div class="block-description">description</div>
```

Comment: Классно) Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Denis https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote